# ms-access: edit form entries using foreign keys

Tags: forms, ms-access

To keep it simple there is the following table relation in ms-access: T_Create (n:1) T_Employee [foreign key is CR_Employee which contains the EM_ID)

The tables look like this: 
T_Create (CR_ID, CR_Employee)
T_Employee (EM_ID, EM_Name)

To show the EM_Name field for my T_Create entries I create a query that joins on T_Employee and gets the field EM_Name. So I receive a list that contains the entries of the T_Create table with the fields CR_ID and EM_Name.

I created a form with help of the query. I want to be able to edit the entries with a dropdown menu and save it in the table T_Create. I know how it works, when I display the CR_Employee foreign key field. But I want to change the value without using this field. The form should update the foreign key in the background. In the form I want to use the text that is linked to the foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want combobox to save the EM_ID but display the EM_Name? Use a multi-column combobox.

RowSource: `SELECT EM_ID, EM_Name FROM T_Employee`
ColumnCount: 2
ColumnWidths: 0";1"
BoundColumn: 1
ControlSource: CR_Employee

BTW, name parts should be in separate fields like: FName, LName, MName. Then RowSource could be: `SELECT EM_ID, LName & ", " & FName AS FName FROM T_Employee;`.

No need to include T_Employee in the form RecordSource unless there are more fields you want to display, such as address info. If you do include T_Employee table then set any controls bound to its fields as Locked Yes and TabStop No.

Comment: Should Names be separated into different fields? What does "First name" mean if you live in China? More like Surname and given name. Though that's not always true either. What about people with one name? Do you make first and last required? More robustly would just be a "Full Name" and a "Call Me By" type fields. Then you make no assumptions about culture.

Comment: All developer preference. If you like Surname as field name then go with. Having name parts in separate fields better manages consistency. So not entered with variations like: John Smith or Carson, Amy. Establish a rule for dealing with one word names (maybe "enter into Surname field"). Sorting and filtering is facilitated.

Comment: But Surname <> Last Name. That's not a preference thing, those are two different concepts. How do you represent [Moon Jae-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Jae-in)'s name in a first name/last name schema?

Comment: Either way, the answer is right, though OP might need to specify the bound column as well.

Comment: Its just a simple example... sure you should separate the name.

But how do I update the table T_Create, if I select the table T_Employee?

I want to output the data of the table T_Create with the Information of table T_Employee (EM_Name). And then I want to have a dropdown menu that lets me change the name (text). In the background it should update the foreign key (CR_Employee) in table T_Create.

Comment: Don't understand issue. If you want to change the employee associated with existing record in T_Create, then select the employee from combobox so the saved EM_ID is changed. If you want to change the name of employee associated with EM_ID (why - marriage, divorce?) then need to do an edit in T_Employees.

Comment: I want the employee name displayed in the form and not the foreign key. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, follow the instructions in my answer.

Comment: I can see the name in the dropdown menu. I want to see it in the input field instead of the ID

Comment: @GR_ it sounds like there are 3 things: input field, name, ID. How are those different?

Comment: If done properly, the combobox will display the descriptive alias and the ID will be hidden. This a common and proven technique. Based on your simple example, the instructions provided should work. If the example does not reflect your data structure, then provide relevant info in your question.

Comment: Now it works. When I restart access it refreshes something, so that everything is displayed correctly. I had to restart access after every change to refresh the fields. Is there another way? I tried the refresh all button but it doesn't work for this form.

Comment: You mean after selecting item from combobox, you have to restart Access, not just close and reopen form? Cannot replicate this issue. Did you remove T_Employee from the RecordSource?